My friend’s university campus in Pixels
My friend who so happens to be doing a Bachelors degree in Digital Marketing sent me this picture of a pixelated version of a map of his university campus. He, being a bright guy told me that he saw something very familiar would be represented if he made it and for that he has decided to make this and pass it to all of his friends in order to challenge them to figure out what he realised. I, for the life of me have no idea what he is on about…

What’s being represented and why?
Hint:

 He told me to tilt my head to the left a little.


Well, if we

 rotate the image through 90 degrees

then

 we get this


which

 has the digits 0..9 in order, each paired with its reflection.

I suppose

 "digital marketing" means marketing of digits.


Fantastic work! You nailed it!
